# Historical notes of filter designs?

Tags: filters

Anyone know what references might have information about the history of any particular filter design?

Since seeing just the equation or implementation hinders the process by which the filter (such as the biquad filter) was actually discovered.

Comment: The answer to this [question](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/189662/what-are-the-differences-between-modern-and-classical-filter-theory/189711#189711) may be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Along the line as Fat32's suggestion to consult IEEE papers, you might try to obtain a copy of "Digital Signal Processing" (IEEE Press Selected Reprint Series), Edited by: Lawrence R. Rabiner and Charles M. Rader, published by: IEEE press (1972).

[image]

That book contains reprints of many early (starting around the middle 1960s), and influential, scholarly papers on digital filtering. And of course those early papers contain references to even earlier papers.

Answer (score 1):

If you are only looking for digital filter design, then R.Hamming's classical book "Digital Filters" might help for further references... You should better consult IEEE papers to track down the invention of many types then...